Symmetric square $L$-functions over imaginary quadratic field
Let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ with class number $h_F = 1$, and $\Gamma = \mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathfrak{O}_F)$. Let $f$ be a Maass cusp form  in the  $L^2$-cuspidal spectrum  of the  Laplace operator  $\varDelta$ on $\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}^3$. For $\mathrm{Re} (s) > 1$ the symmetric square $L$-function attached to $ f    $ is defined by
\begin{equation}
    L (s, \mathrm{Sym}^2 f   ) = \zeta_F (2s)  \sum_{\mathfrak{n}   \subset \mathfrak{O} }  \frac {\lambda_f(  \mathfrak{n}^2)  } {\mathrm{N} (\mathfrak{n})^{  s} }. 
\end{equation}
My question is: What does the approximate functional equation (or even just the functional equation) for $L(s, \text{Sym}^2 f)$ look like? I see some results for the case when $F = \mathbb{Q}(i)$, such as in Prime Geodesic Theorem in the 3-dimensional Hyperbolic Space, but I'm wondering if there's a slightly more general version available anywhere?

For any L-function, can't you deduce the Gamma-factors of the sym^2 from the Gamma factors of the original L-function?

@DavidFarmer Thanks for comment! I found the definition of the gamma factor for the Lankin-Selberg L-function in  [IK,p132], so perhaps I can obtain its functional equation. But how can I derive the approximate functional equation for it?

Rubinstein gives a general smoothed approximate functional equation which only needs the data in the functional equation: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412181
If you want something in the style of Hardy-Littlewood, the error term will be large so you probably can't use it to prove anything.
